# Download or get the contents of the file from private repo github

Tags: laravel, github-api

I have a laravel app in which I wants to make a functionality by using I can download the latest commit files of an private github repo. I am using github apis and token to get the latest commit but not be able to download them. I have tried to get the content of a file using "raw_file" json provided by github api.
I am using this github api to get the latest commits and the file content.
[https://api.github.com/repos/{$owner}/{$repo}/commits/{$latestCommitSHA}](https://api.github.com/repos/%7B$owner%7D/%7B$repo%7D/commits/%7B$latestCommitSHA%7D)

And this is the response provided by above api:
https://prnt.sc/Mo-Og6vJkV6P

I have tried to use different php/laravel github libraries but did not worked.

Comment: I suggest posting some code snippets in where you actually handle the downloads. That would help understand the problem. There is no way for me to know what the exact problem is without looking at some code.